# react native json parsing

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Is it possible to remove/ignore featured image in react native app while fetching data from WordPress blog by using `react-native-html-view` dependency?

[image]

I'm using:

```
"native-base": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.46.4",
    "react-native-fit-image": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-interactable": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "wpapi": "^1.1.2"
```

Actually, I only need the text of blog not images and using `react-native-html-view` I get images too which is not my requirement.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      ActivityIndicator,
      ListView,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      View
    } from 'react-native';
    import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';
    export default class Home extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isLoading: true
   }
 }
    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://www.cardory.co.uk/jan/json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.items),
    }, function() {
      // do something with new state
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
    }

      render() {
if (this.state.isLoading) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 60}}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
}

return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 60}}>
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData) =>

      <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Text style={styles.titleHeading}>{rowData.title}</Text>
        </CardItem>

        <CardItem>
          <HTMLView value={rowData.content_html}/>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>

    }
  />
  </View>
);
      }
    }
    const styles=StyleSheet.create({
      textHeading:{
fontSize:20,
marginTop:20
      },
      titleHeading:{
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'black',
        alignItems:'center',
      }
    });
    module.export=Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data in HTMLView after removing image tag like follow so if there is no image in HTML string it will display without image

`<HTMLView value={rowData.content_html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"")}/>`